# How to properly implement custom squash function in TF2.0 (custom layer or other)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to implement a simple capsnet model in TF2.0.

So far, I have added a few conv2d layers, and a reshape layer, but I need to add a squash function now. The issue is that `tf.norm()` will send me to `NaN` land since I'm squashing entire vectors, so I have to use a custom squash function. I've never written a custom layer before, and I basically just used the template from the tutorial and added the math function under the `call()`.

Since I am doing this all inside of a `keras.models.Sequential` model, I wasn't sure how to get the output after the first couple of layers so I just decided to make the squash function its own layer in the model. I feel like this is probably completely and totally wrong, so I'm looking for some input on the best way to go about this.

Should I be using a `keras.Model` for this at all, or should I use the new eager execution feature to just pass the tensors through the layers manually? If it's okay to use the `SquashLayer()` that I have implemented, then what do I pass through as an argument so that I get the proper output to pass into the next layer?

```
class SquashLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_units):
        super(SquashLayer, self).__init__()
        self.output_units = output_units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_variable(
          'kernel', [input_shape[-1], self.output_units])

    def call(self, input):
        squared_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(input), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        safe_norm = tf.sqrt(squared_norm + 1e-7)
        squash_factor = squared_norm / (1. + squared_norm)
        unit_vector = input / safe_norm
        return squash_factor * unit_vector

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=9, strides=1, padding='valid', activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv1'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=9, strides=2, padding='valid', activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv2'),
    keras.layers.Reshape((-1, caps1_n_caps, caps1_n_dims)),
    SquashLayer()
    ])
```

Comment: It should work fine except for `SquashLayer` constructore in `Sequential` not getting `output_units` argument. And you are not using `self.kernel` in your custom layer, what's the point of it? Otherwise you should be fine with `tf.keras.models.Sequential`, `tf.keras.Model` would be good architectures needing more flexibility (e.g. DenseNets). Last but not least, please update your code with stuff like `caps1_n_caps` to make your problem reproducible.